# Algorithms in checking overlapping genomic regions

Tags: java, algorithm, list, bioinformatics

I have two large list of genomic regions in the form of two bed files, and there are many tools help me check the overlap of the two list.

Any given region (one from list A, another from list B), as long as they overlap in any of their coordinates, they are called overlap. There are available tools to do that. But I wish to write an efficient algorithms that I can maintain a hash-table like structure in list A, and then I iterate all the regions in list B, and for each regions from list B I can use a quick algorithms to tell if some of the regions in list A overlap with this specific regions from list B.

I specifically need an efficient solutions since both lists are very large. Thanks very much.

Comment: what is a genomic region conceptually?

Comment: genomic region for example tells where a gene or binding site is, here is one example, chr8 1288888 12888890, that is a genomic region.

Comment: @UmNyobe In the example, the genomic feature starts at 1288888 relatively to the beginning of chromosome 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to:

1. Create a 1-dimensional R-tree of the regions in one BED file. Insert a range for each exon.
2. For each region in the other BED file, search the R-tree for
   intersections of each of that region's exons.

For Java, there are multiple implementations of R-trees. One I've used that supports 1-dimensional ranges is [SIRtree](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/javadoc/com/vividsolutions/jts/index/strtree/SIRtree.html), in the library [JTS](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/JTSHome.htm). It provides simple methods to insert ranges and search for intersections.

Any data structure represented in memory will be a scalability concern for sufficiently large BED files. You can address that by either increasing the amount of memory available to the VM (hardware and the -Xmx setting) or by representing your data structure on disk.

Comment: Wow!!!! Thank you so much, that is exactly what I am looking for. Admire your insight and skill.

Comment: Additionally, do you think for very large BED file, if I use FM index instead of R-tree, will that helps to reduce memory usage?

Comment: You're welcome. I haven't yet used an FM-index. Not sure how it would apply to range intersection rather than sequence searching. That might merit a separate question.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I will first use R-tree and then do some research on FM index application then.

Comment: @Andy_Thomas FM index is a data-structure for string comparisons. It's reversible and compact. However, it bears no relationship to the current question. FM index is more likely be used in genomic alignment, such as DNA sequence comparisons.

Comment: @Wise_Will_Win Andy's solution is a great start. I'm not so sure FM-index has anything to do with this context.

Comment: After a comprehensive reading on FM index, @StudentT is exactly correct, FM index won't be suitable for this problem. Thanks very much for your help!